# iOS : Shows different date timings in NSLog and Preview box

Tags: ios, nsdate

[image]

Why it shows two different dates in `NSLog` and in preview box?

Output:

1. NSLog - 2014-05-07 19:07:57 IST
2. Preview box - 2014-05-07 13:37:57 +0000

Comment: The dates are in 2 different time zones. 
IST = India Standard Time
+ 0000 = Greenwich Mean Time or Unknown time zone. It means that for more info documentation, it does not get time from your local computer/Xcode setting.

Comment: so basically, it's the same time, just different representations

Comment: I just pasted the answer below. You may accept the answer if you want. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates are in 2 different time zones.

IST = India Standard Time 
+0000 = Greenwich Mean Time or Unknown time zone. It means that for more info documentation, it does not get time from your local computer/Xcode setting.